# What can I do if someone is spoofing my site?

Tags: legal

Someone registered a domain name that is close to mine used a different suffix (.info) and ripped off the UI. They took a screenshot of our homepage put it on their site and put up a modal window asking people to take some quiz.  What can I do? Do I complain to the company that gave him that domain?

They also using tweeter and posted a youtube video of our site with their name on it.

Comment: This is a legal question, not a programming one. You need to consult a lawyer, not a programmer. Such questions are off-topic here.

Comment: Is your business name trademarked? Did they steal your content? Or they just mimic your website?

Comment: they stole our content. it basically either a screenshot of our homepage or our application in iframe.

Comment: Is it a screenshot, like an image? Or the actual webpage? If it is the actual webpage then you can do something it programmatically.

Comment: I confirmed. It is an image. Screenshot of our homepage.

Comment: I  might also suggest you check on the more business oriented site (also on the StackExchange network), http://answers.onstartups.com/

Answer (score 3):

The wikipedia article have an example of [take down action](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_Copyright_Infringement_Liability_Limitation_Act#Takedown_example)

Comment: That should only be used if copyrights are violated. We don't know if that is true in this case.

Comment: I guess you can claim copyright on your site's look and feel (appearance).

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet would be contacting the website owner and asking them to take it down (check whois for email address). If you get no reply, then contact their host. Even if it is not illegal, it is obviously not ethically right and they might be able to help you.